# How can I get the name of the file I'm currently visiting with Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

While I'm visiting, let's say, a declaration (`Decl` in Clang library), how can I get the name of the file where this `Decl` has been written ?

There is a [FileData](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1FileData.html) class, but I can't find any other class allowing me to get this `FileData`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask the SourceManager for the FileEntry of the current file.

For example in a matcher callback:

```
void MyMatcher::run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& Result) {
    ASTContext* Context = Result.Context;
    if (const Decl* D = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<Decl>("MyDecl")) {
        SourceManager& SrcMgr = Context->getSourceManager();
        const FileEntry* Entry = SrcMgr.getFileEntryForID(SrcMgr.getFileID(D.getCaretLocation()));
        const char* FileName = Entry->getName();
    }
}
```